# Center element in parent until it reaches top-left bounds, then stop centering and show scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, centering

I want to center an element within a parent. That's easy enough with transform, flexbox, grid and so on...
The problem is the overflow-behavior. **When the parent shrinks below the dimensions of the child, scrollbars appear. But they do not allow me to scroll to the top-left of the child.** Here's what I mean:
[gif animation showing window-resizing and the css behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGA5u.gif)

This example uses flexbox for it's centering, html below:

```css
b {
  color: white;
}

html {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 84px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  bottom: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.content {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- omitted head -->

<body>

  <header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="content">
      <b>Lorem</b> Lots of Lorem ipsum... <b>quod</b>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

What I want to achieve looks more like this:
[gif animation showing window-resizing and the css behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7AIN.gif)

In this example I didn't use flexbox-centering. I wrapped the content within a container that has it's margin set to: 0 auto. This will achieve the wanted behavior on the x-axis, but not the y-axis. How can I achieve this on both axes?

Below the html and css of the second example using a container and auto-margin for centering:

```css
b {
  color: white;
}

html {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 84px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  bottom: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  /* display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; */
  overflow: auto;
}

div.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
}

div.content {
  /* flex-shrink: 0; */
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- omitted head -->

<body>

  <header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <b>Lorem</b> Lots of Lorem ipsum... <b>quod</b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Ah... I hope to find a solution that doesn't use javascript for this behavior. In case I find the solution, I'll post it with a corresponding gif.

Comment: What behavior you wanted on y-axis

Comment: I wanted to be able to scroll upwards to see the child completely. WIth flexbox I can only scroll down.

Comment: Your `child` is visible : Lorem Lots of Lorem ipsum... quod in the 2nd snippet

Comment: Yes, but in that example I'm not using flexbox to center the div.content in main. There it's only centered on the x-axis and div.content sticks to the top. I need the content to be centered if the window gets larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex` on the `.container` and `margin: auto` on the `.content`  .

This is a method to solve the centering problems of `flex` and by this way it will center  `.content`

```css
b {
  color: white;
}

html {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 84px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84px;
  bottom: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  /*display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; */
  overflow: auto;
}

div.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
}

div.content {
  /* flex-shrink: 0; */
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- omitted head -->

<body>

  <header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <b>Lorem</b> Lots of Lorem ipsum... <b>quod</b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: perfect solution! Is it okay if I add a gif to your answer?

Comment: Why not, you can do that if you want @HaraldLesan

Comment: By the way how you make gif, it comes handy most times @HaraldLesan which app or site

Comment: 1. I record it with this tool: https://www.screentogif.com/
2. I resize it on here: https://ezgif.com/resize

Comment: Thanks for edit @HaraldLesan. If you like to upvote , you can do that by the upper arrow in top-left part of answer